# How to prevent scroll to top after deleting an item or filtering data flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a flat list with infinite scrolling and a delete items feature.

But every time I delete an item (using a filter) my flat list scrolls to the top.

#### Delete Function

```js
       const deleteItemById = async entry => {
         const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
         return item.id != entry.id;
         });
         await setNotificationData(filteredData);
       };
```

#### Delete Button

```js
       <IconButton
          onPress={() => {
          const notificationToken = globalVariable.token;
          const deleteNotificationAPI = async () => {
            try {
              await axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}${data.id}`,
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: notificationToken,
                  },
                }
              );
              } catch (err) {
                  console.error(err);
              }
              deleteItemById(data);
              };
              deleteNotificationAPI();
              }}
          style={IconButton7a33adf1}
          icon={'Foundation/trash'}
          size={25}
          color={theme.colors.trashCan}
         />
```

#### FlatList

This is the flat list that I have been using with `renderItem` function. It is working fine, deleting the items, it is just scrolling to the top after the filter, I believe this is happening because is rerendering the `flatList`.

```js
    <FlatList
       listKey={'s8qdyDKI'}
       data={data}
       initialNumToRender={30}
       windowSize={40}
       key={data.length}
       ListFooterComponent={<LoadNotifications />}
       keyExtractor={item => item?.id || item?.uuid || item}
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <Notifications
          data={item}
          style={notificationStyles.item}
       />
       )}
       onEndReached={oneMoreNotificationPage}
       onEndReachedThreshold={0.15}
       contentContainerStyle={
       notificationStyles.FlatList21f2035aContent
       }
       numColumns={1}
```

#### renderItem

```js
      function Notifications({ data }) {
    return (
      <>
        <View
          style={[notificationStyles.Viewcd452035,
          ]}
          >
          <View
          style={[notificationStyles.Viewb8b059f4,]}
           >
            <View
               style={[
                  notificationStyles.Viewb34b4333,]}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={[
                        notificationStyles.Text812c3e6d,]}
                      ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
                      numberOfLines={1}
                    >
                      {data?.title}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={notificationStyles.Viewdebd3207}>
                    <View style={notificationStyles.View3821c683}>
                      <Text
                        style={[
                          notificationStyles.Text13ddebce,]}
                        numberOfLines={1}
                        ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
                      >
                        {data?.created_at}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={notificationStyles.Viewc2817b4e}>
                      <IconButton
                        onPress={() => {
                          const notificationToken =
                            globalVariable.token;
                          const deleteNotificationAPI = async () => 
                            {
                              try {
                                await axios.delete(
                                `${BASE_URL}${data?.id}`,
                                 {
                                  headers: {
                                    Authorization: 
                                     notificationToken,
                                  },
                                }
                              );
                            } catch (err) {
                              console.error(err);
                            }
                            deleteItemById(data);
                            console.log('after call');
                          };
                          deleteNotificationAPI();
                        }}
                        style= 
                          {notificationStyles.IconButton7a33adf1}
                        icon={'Foundation/trash'}
                        size={25}
                        color={theme.colors.trashCan}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have showing where the `Flatlist` and `renderItem` is being created?

Comment: Sure, already did as you asked @PhantomSpooks Thanks for your response

Comment: Are you sure the `J` tag is relevant? Please read the description of the tag to be sure it's about what you think it is.